# Find values of the constants $k$ and $m$, if possible, that will make the function continuous everywhere.

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics, continuity

> Find values of the constants $k$ and $m$, if possible, that will make the funtion continuous everywhere.
>   $$
>     f(x)
>   = \begin{cases}
>       x^2+5,    &      x >     2, \\
>       m(x+1)+k, & -1 < x \leq  2, \\
>       2x^3+x+7, &      x \leq -1.
>     \end{cases}
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you want

$$\lim_{x \to 2^+ }(x^2+5)=\lim_{x \to 2^{-}}(m(x+1)+k)$$
$$\lim_{x \to -1^+ }(m(x+1)+k)=\lim_{x \to -1^{-}}(2x^3+x+7)$$